# Pandas: Create New Column with Value if Current Column Contains Any String in a List

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following sample dataframe.  "PN" is a string column.

```
   ID   PN
    A   1111
    B   220
    C   4422
    D   1234
    E   9890
    F   1323
```

The logic I want to implement is: if the string value in PN is in a list ['1111', '1234', '2222', '3333', '4422'], then create a new column called "GCS" and label the corresponding cell value as "PGC".  Otherwise, label the cell as "All".

Below is the desired table I am looking for.

```
ID  PN      GCS
A   1111    PGC
B   220     ALL
C   4422    PGC
D   1234    PGC
E   9890    ALL
F   1323    ALL
```

Below is the code I tried:

```
ME_List = ['1111', '1234', '2222', '3333', '4422']

for i in ME_LIST: 
    df_EVENT5_22['GCS'] = np.where(df_EVENT5_22['PN'].str.contains([i]), 'PGC', 'All')
```

This is the error:

```
NameError: name 'ME_LIST' is not defined
```

Comment: @jpp Thanks for marking, I had a hunch it was a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the error? Your variable name is not written correctly in the for loop. `ME_List` vs `ME_LIST`.

Comment: Yes, but that isn't the only problem.